# I can't plot my Matplotlib prediction, I keep getting memory error

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot predictions as directed by Krill Emeranko's super data science guide but i am having a hard time doing this as I keep getting this error

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 443. GiB for an array with shape (13500200, 4400) and data type float64
```

The code i am running:

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

X_set, y_set = X_train, y_train
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() -1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
                     np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() -1, stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))
plt.contourf(X1, X2, model.predict(np.array(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape),
                                        alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('red', 'green'))))
plt.xlim(X1.min(), X1.max())
plt.ylim(X2.min(), X2.max())

for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
     plt.scatter(X_set[y_set == j, 0], X_set[y_set == j, 1],
                      c = ListedColormap(('red', 'green'))(i), label = j)
plt.title('Logistic Regression (Training set)')
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Estimated salary')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: The error message is self explanatory. Your matrix is to big to plot

Comment: You really need a larger step size.  Things work much easier with `linspace(start=X_set[:, 0].min() -1, stop=X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, num=200))` to get e.g. 200 steps. With `arange` the number of steps can be much too large or much to small depending on the values in `X_set`.

Comment: Question for you: How many pixels does your monitor have? If you're hoping to look at a 13500200 x 4400 array, it must be pretty dang big